# Converting image to NSData to save in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to store an image in `core data`.

My `core data` properties file requires the image to be in `NSData` :

```
 import Foundation
 import CoreData

 extension Item {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<TaskItem> {
    return NSFetchRequest<TaskItem>(entityName: "Item");
    }

    @NSManaged public var itemImage: NSData?
}
```

However when I'm trying to save to `core data` using:

```
    @IBAction func saveBtnTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {


        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        let item = Item(context: context)

        let imageData: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(taskImage.image!, 0.2) 

        item.itemImage = imageData

        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

       }
       navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Data?' to specified type 'NSData'
```

I thought I was doing it right, but it's not working for me. Could someone please give me an idea of how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't save image in your core data, it's not efficent, just save the image to disk and save the image name/path to your coredata

Comment: You can save image to local directory and then save Path/URL to coredata.

Comment: If all else fails, I will go that route

Comment: Always store an image through a ValueTransformer. If the datablob is too big for core data it will store it separately on disk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIImageJPEGRepresentation` returns a `Data?` value.
This can be bridged to `NSData?` with `as`. Then use optional binding
(`if let`) to safely unwrap the optional:

```
if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(...) as NSData? {
     // Now `imageData` is a `NSData` object.
     item.itemImage = imageData
} else {
     // Conversion to JPEG data failed.
}
```

You should also consult the section "Binary Large Data Objects (BLOBs)"
in the "Core Data Programming Guide" about the implications of
storing binary data directly in the database, and possible alternatives.